# Running Flask app in vscode - Error: Could not import App

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I get this error running a Flask app out of Visual Studio Code (VsCode):

> *Serving Flask APP "myWebSite.py"
>   *Environment: production WARNING:
>   Do not use the development server in a production environment. 
>   Use a production WSGI server instead.
>   * Debug mode:off Useage: flask run [OPTIONS]
>
> **Error: Could not import "myWebSite"**

---

When I run it out of another PC with  Visual Studio Code it runs fine. What could it be?

<sub>Note: I'm answering my own question to help others in the future.</sub>

Comment: Downvoter care to explain, 220 views in 8 months with a working answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to check you have all the requirements installed using pip.

Then the trick is you need to select the correct debugger in Visual Studio Code:

> Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)

If you have another selected such as **Python: Flask** it causes the error.

---

Another way is right click on the contents of  myWebSite.py and `Python Run in Terminal`.